# $2\cos(3x) = 1$ Trig Equation with Multiple Angles

Tags: trigonometry

I am confused on how I can get three answers to this question all in the interval of (0,$\pi$]

My steps for the original problem:

- $2\cos(3x)=1$
- $\cos(3x)=1/2$
- $(3x) = \pi/3$ **and** $(3x)=5\pi/3$
- Divide by three
- $x = \pi/9$ **and** $x = 5\pi/9$

These were my final answers but I'm missing $7\pi/9$

I know I can add $2\pi n$ but that would be out of range.

Can anyone explain how I can get $7\pi/9$? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $3x=7\pi/3$ yields another solution.  Notice all solutions are
$$
3x = \frac{\pi}{3} +2 \pi k
$$
and
$$
3x = \frac{5\pi}{3} + 2 \pi k
$$
where $k$ is an integer.  Which ones will yields solutions with $x$ in $[0, \pi]$?

Comment: Oh okay! So when I add pi/9 and 6pi/9 I would get 7pi/9. Thank you very much I appreciate it

Comment: @JeremyHernandez You are welcome.  Be sure to upvote/accept answer that are helpful to you.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Another one is $3x=2\pi+\pi/3$, so $x=7\pi/9$.